# How to setup EC2 instance (Bastion Host) to have root volume be ephemeral and another volume be EBS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I am trying to change a bastion host EC2 that is currently stood up with terraform and has the root volume set to EBS storage. I want to have the root volume be ephemeral so that every time the bastion host is reset/restarted the root storage is cleaned out. I still want to maintain the EBS volume. After reading the current AMI json mapping, the EBS volume is mapped to '/dev/sda1'. Can I simply map this volume to '/dev/sdh'? My thinking is that /dev/sda1 will then default to ephemeral and that sda1 is the root volume from the information I gather AWS documentation. I could be missing something but I don't see anything about setting the root volume to ephemeral and having a separate EBS volume.

Answer (score 0):

Instance store as the root volume is only available for specific instance family only.

[image]

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/RootDeviceStorage.html

To select the root volume as instance store you can follow the below aws provided steps:
[image]